# Count of correct and incorrect matches

Tags: r

I am trying to mutate two new columns Correct_Match and Incorrect_Match.

*Correct Match* - how many number of values in `Y1, Y2` matches with the columns `X1,X2,X3` (ignoring NA match)

*InCorrect Match* - how many number of values in `Y1, Y2` not matches with the columns `X1,X2,X3` (ignoring NA match)

Code:

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c("alpha in","for beta","for gamma","for ceta"),
                 X2 = c("for ceta",NA,"for new",NA),
                 X3 = c("for new1","for new2","for new3",NA),

                 Y1 = c("for new2","for beta", "for new4", "for new4"),
                 Y2 = c("for ceta","for new2", "for new5", "for new3")
)
df
         X1       X2       X3       Y1       Y2
1  alpha in for ceta for new1 for new2 for ceta
2  for beta     <NA> for new2 for beta for new2
3 for gamma  for new for new3 for new4 for new5
4  for ceta     <NA>     <NA> for new4 for new3
```

Expected output:

```
         X1       X2       X3       Y1       Y2 Correct_Match InCorrect_Match
1  alpha in for ceta for new1 for new2 for ceta             1               1
2  for beta     <NA> for new2 for beta for new2             2               1
3 for gamma  for new for new3 for new4 for new5             0               2
4  for ceta     <NA>     <NA> for new4 for new3             1               1
```

Comment: If you want to ignore `NA` values how is `InCorrect_Match` 1 in row 2  ? Also `Correct_Match` is row 4 should be 0 and incorrect should be 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, we can use `apply` row-wise and add counts of matching and non-matching rows

```
x_cols <-  grep("X", names(df))
y_cols <- grep("Y", names(df))

df[c("Correct_Match", "InCorrect_Match")] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) 
        c(sum(x[y_cols] %in% x[x_cols]), sum(!x[y_cols] %in% x[x_cols]))))

df
#         X1       X2       X3       Y1       Y2 Correct_Match InCorrect_Match
#1  alpha in for ceta for new1 for new2 for ceta             1               1
#2  for beta     <NA> for new2 for beta for new2             2               0
#3 for gamma  for new for new3 for new4 for new5             0               2
#4  for ceta     <NA>     <NA> for new4 for new3             0               2
```